# ¿Como saber DB_HOST desde cpanel (produccion)?

Tags: php, api, cpanel, datos

Es que estoy aprendiendo a hacer un api en phpLaravel pero en la seccion de conexiones en el archivo `.env` me pide las credenciales de la conexion a la BD y pues no se de donde sacar los campos `DB_HOST` y `DB_PORT` de la base de datos desde cpanel, las otras si se como sacarlas.

He visto tutoriales y documentación pero no se aun desde el cpanel, como acceder a esa info.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mejor será que te contactes con el área de soporte

Comment: Puedes seguir como muestran en esta pagina. [Url de la web](https://blog.infranetworking.com/montar-proyecto-laravel-cpanel/)

Comment: de hecho creeria que es la mejor opcion

Comment: Por lo general, en DB_HOST se usa la IP del servidor, pero eso no es suficiente, en CPANEL debes configurar [MySQL para permitir conexión remota](https://www.pickaweb.es/ayuda/como-establecer-conexiones-mysql-remotas-con-cpanel/) y el problema principal es que debes tener una IP fija o actualizar la configuración cada que cambie tu IP, porque la mayoría de servidores no permiten acceso total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en la mayoria de servidores apache en DB_HOST suele ser "localhost" en cuando al PORT suele ser 3306, sin embargo le recomendaria probarlo primero ya que no estoy muy seguro de esto, también verifique si tiene los accesos necesarios para modificar la base de datos.

Comment: es que si lo dejo localhost no estaria apuntando al cpanel si no al xampp local que tengo

Comment: bueno si tiene razon, osea que la unica forma de hacer pruebas mientras creo el api es localmente? no puedo apuntar a produccion desde mi pc?

Comment: Hola @Wilmilcard creo que te estás enredando sin necesidad. cPanel te ofrece mecanismos para hacer administración de la BD en el servicio de hosting. Ello es diferente de accesarla desde la aplicación para responder a solicitudes de páginas. En los servicios compartidos los datos que te ofrece la respuesta son correctos. Y, se usan para que tu aplicación pueda responder contando con la BD. Si necesitas subir a ella info ubicada en tu BD local debes exportarla e importala luego usando las utilidades que te brinda cPanel. Hacerlo por conexiones directas puede generar problemas de seguridad.

Comment: @Wilmilcard Adicionalmente. Usando la utilidad de gestion de Bases de datos de cPanel debes crear un usuario para la BD, asociarlo a la misma y darle privilegios suficientes. No necesariamente es el mismo usuario que empleas en su entorno de pruebas locales y no debe ser el usuario que te asigno el servicio de hosting (por razones de seguridad, más aún si tienes derecho a crear múltiples BD) y, ese usuario y la contraseña que le asignes van a .env